# Specify a covariance matrix

Tags: r, bayes

I'm trying to replicate the analysis presented on the bottenada.se and described in the [ADA repository](http://github.com/MansMeg/Ada/blob/master/Demonstration/demo.md). Although the demo file is quite detailed, I didn't grasp where those values for the "C0" component come from. I would like to try other m0 combinations, but I couldn't understand how can I generate C0 values to fill in the model. The help file says:

"You need to define your prior for the election in two steps. First give your best estimates where you believe the election will end. Then you need to specify this as a covariance matrix. In Ada we specify our priors the following way (as of august 9)."

```
 priors2014$m0 <- c(0.227, 0.0665, 0.0645, 0.0595, 0.353, 0.08, 0.08, 0.081)
    priors2014$C0 <- diag(c(0.001024, 0.000144, 0.000144, 0.000144, 0.001024, 0.000625, 
    0.000625, 0.000625))
colnames($)priors2014C0 <- rownames($)priors2014C0 <- names(priors2014$m0) <- c("M", 
    "FP", "C", "KD", "S", "V", "MP", "SD")
```

Comment: They're nice round numbers divided by 1,000,000. It seems like they just chose the biggest ones to correspond to the biggest `m0` values, which seem to be clustered around 0.3, 0.06, and 0.08. There might be some tighter relationship, but my guess is there's nothing rigorous behind it. That, or they're actually using point estimates from some other model.

Comment: They state in the paragraph above that "We used our model based mainly on previous election results from Statistics Sweden and incorporating small party effects. We tried different ways to asses the priors based on the previous elections 2010 and 2006 to put the probability mass higher for smaller parties." So these could very well be quite literally derived from prior knowledge.

Comment: @ssdecontrol That was the closest reasonable explanation so far, thanks. But it doesn't fit well though.                         For instance: m0 <- c(0.227, 0.0665, 0.0645, 0.0595, 0.353, 0.08, 0.08, 0.081)                                                  m0/1000000
[1] 0.0000002270 0.0000000665 0.0000000645 0.0000000595 0.0000003530 0.0000000800 0.0000000800 0.0000000810               If you I do apply this reasoning using previous election result then, for the firs cell I should see something like: 0.3006/1000000 = 0.0000003006; everything seems to me too much arbitrary.

Comment: It seems that if I sum up 2006 and 2010 election outcomes and divide by 2, then take this value and divide by some arbitrary number like: ((30.06+26.23)/100)/2,  then taking the product of 0.2814/275 yields ~ 0.001023 which is the closest to "0.001024" in the first cell. However, if I divide the other values for the same number (275), I got completely disparate results to feed in, which sounds completely arbitrary. What is the reason behind it? Any reading recommendation on this would be kind.

Comment: They might in fact be arbitrary.